# nifi processor cron scheduling

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, apache-nifi, quartz

I am trying to setup a cron schedule in nifi which runs every minute from 9AM till 16PM from sunday to thrusday.
I am using following expression but the nifi flow will not trigger.

0 0/1 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU *

I am using containarized image of nifi  avaliable form docker hub. https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/builds

I have tried to validate the expression using cronmaker and it seems that expression is valid. please help.

Comment: wich processor do you schedule ?

Comment: Processor name is generate flow file

Comment: Your expression is working on my Nifi, check logs and nifi time in the GUI and in Linux container.

Comment: many thanks maxime and pdeuxa for looking into. Yes the container timezone was not set causing the issue.